# Functional and Euler-Lagrange equation

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, euler-lagrange-equation, image-processing

I study the functional $F_\epsilon$ (see picture) in $\phi$ ($c_1$ and $c_2$ are constants).

[image]

From its expression I try to write the Euler-Lagrange equation associated to ϕ. Only for that the author introduces an artificial variable t which represents the time (see second image) in order to solve the equation by a gradient descent.
[image]

But I do not understand where the t comes from in view of the Euler-Lagrange equation nor the method. In fact at first I do not know this technique (and I do not understand it) of introducing an artificial time parameter $t$.
Thank you in advance for your help.